# OData filtering by decimal column cause out of range exception

Tags: odata

I have decimal(6,2) column on my database. In my API I have OData endpoint to table with this column. When I send a request with filter whitch is out of range that decimal (for example 11111) I get out of range exception, but I want to receive just empty list, not error. Is there any setting on OData to achieve that or some other solution?

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: return _context.VatRates.Select(u => new VatRateRow
{
    Uid = u.Uid,
    Code = u.Code,
    Value =  u.Value,
    IsActive = u.IsActive
});